# Sales Order Grid Custom Field value not saved

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid, sales-order, custom

I have create a custom field(**zipcode**) in **sales_order** and **sales_order_grid**, after that i try to save to database while click  **placeorder** the order in frontend,so try to use `checkout_submit_all_after` event, But its not save my custom field value.

**what i did:**

**vendor/module/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
          <observer name="custom_checkout_submit_all_after"
                    instance="vendor\Module\Observer\SalesOrderPlaceAfter"
                    />
      </event>
  </config>
```

Then create a Observer to to save Custom Field Value.

**vendor/module/Observer/SalesOrderPlaceAfter.php:**

```
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class SalesOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            try {
                $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
                $order->setZipcode("604503");
                $order->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

But its have save My custom Field value, Suggest me How to fix this.

Comment: Move the `events.xml` to `vendor\module\etc\events.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to set the custom attribute data to order, it's better if we use `before` saving observer. For example: `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`.

```
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $order->setZipcode($feeAmount);
```

Order table and order grid are in sync:

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
   <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_column" xsi:type="string">
                     sales_order.your_column
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```